# Horror book about werewolf-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I'm trying to remember the title of a book that I have read a few times.  I would have first read it somewhere around 1990.  While not having anything to do with the book I seem to have bad luck with this particular title, I first bought it brand new and it was destroyed in a fire a few years later, the next time I got it it was destroyed in a flood.  Here are the particulars I can remember about the book.

The protagonist is a male with the stereotypical reluctant werewolf syndrome and the antagonist is a female that has fully embraced her new nature.  (I know this seems to point towards Mark of the Werewolf by Jeffrey Sackett but I'm positive it's not that book.)  Where this differs from typical werewolf books is the affliction is the result of an insect bite (if I remember correctly) and the female is searching for the male because her breeding cycle is getting near (happens every 5 years.)

The only other thing in the book that I remember clearly is at one point there is a gang member in a van(?) complaining to himself that every one mispronounces his name as Jesus instead of the correct Spanish pronunciation.

If memory serves the front cover was a male mouth with fangs and teeth bared as if in pain.

I don't recall if the book was released long before I read it, or if it was a new publication at the time, only that I bought it brand new, although nothing sticks out to mark it as other than contemporary for the time.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! There is quite a bit of nice detail here. If you remember anything else about the plot though that would be helpful to [edit] in. There’s nothing to worry about, about this being in the wrong place as it is perfectly appropriate here.  Note that there is also [literature.se] that also accepts identification questions in case you need that. Though please don’t cross post a question!

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: http://www.felicityheaton.com/blog/category/romance-books/craved-by-an-alpha/ - Far too late on, but similar themes.